# Any reason that .distinct() is outputting multiple rows? - Django/PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Is there any reason that this query `Finances.objects.order_by('payout').distinct('payout')` is still returning multiple rows? It returns 3 rows.

I have an aggregate function getting the sum of the rows in the database. That looks like this:

```
@property
    def Calculate_bank(self):
        totalpayout = Finances.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('payout'))['payout__sum'] or 0.00 
        totalwithdraw = Finances.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('withdraw'))['withdraw__sum'] or 0.00 
        totalbank = totalpayout - totalwithdraw

        return totalbank

    @property
    def Calculate_cash(self):
        totalwithdraw = Finances.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('withdraw'))['withdraw__sum'] or 0.00
        totalcash = Finances.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('cash'))['cash__sum'] or 0.00 
        totalcoh = totalwithdraw - totalcash

        return totalcoh
```

I then use the `Finances.objects.order_by('payout').distinct('payout')` query in view.py and it displays three rows of the same output? If I add more `order_by` or `distinct` filters, it duplicated the three rows already showing. I have tried filtering by id as well.

[image: output]

If I do not use the distinct, it shows a new row for everytime there is an entry in the database.

**view.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def finances(request):
    viewfinances = Finances.objects.order_by('payout').distinct('payout')

return render(request, 'portal/finances.html', {"viewfinances": viewfinances})
```

**template**

```
<div class="container">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item active" aria-current="true">Finances</li>
                {% for finances in viewfinances %}
                <span class="list-group-item">Cash Available In Bank: <strong>{{ finances.Calculate_bank }}</strong></span>
                {% endfor %}
                {% for finances in viewfinances %}
                <span class="list-group-item">Cash Available On Hand: <strong>{{ finances.Calculate_cash }}</strong></span>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add the view and template

Comment: Your properties `Calculate_bank` and `Calculate_cash` return the exact same value for every instance? You may have three unique rows but you just output the same for each one, what exactly are you trying to do with those properties?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have updated that and that did not change anything. Still getting the same 3 rows of output.

Comment: What did you update?  If you add `{{ finances.id }}` to each row I suspect you will get different values. Your issue is the properties, they don't make any sense, you need to explain what the intention behind them is

Comment: @IainShelvington what I am trying to do with those are say I have Payout=500, Withdraw = 200, Cash = 100. Payout - Withdraw = 300 (which is totalbank). Then I am doing Withdraw - Cash = 100 (which is 100). I am displaying the differences to show how much money is in bank account and how much cash is on hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246305/discussion-between-ckcdevrich-and-iain-shelvington).